# Cocos2d-x: Display japanese characters issue

Tags: visual-studio-2013, cocos2d-x

I'm developing a mini game which display a list of japanese strings using CCLabelTTF.
But it just display like `"???"`.
I have already searched on goolge but still do not know why.
I'm using Visual Studio 2013, Cocos2d-x 2.2.4.
Can anyone give me a solution ?

```
char* text = "仕事";

 pLabelTTF = CCLabelTTF::create(text, "Arial", 10.0f);
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you share some code to show how you use cclabelttf ...  What font you are using ?

Comment: Hi  Blisskarthik, i edited the question, you think cause of the font?

Comment: It works fine for me use ccstring and give a try

Comment: Oh, i have tried, it works fine with that one.
My fault, i did not explain enough.
cause i have an array like: 
static char* textlist[5] ={"仕事","仕事","仕事","仕事","仕事"} then i get value from that array and add 5 CClabelTTF but when i debug it's "???", please tell me what i was wrong? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is save your source code file as UTF-8 without BOM

Answer (score 1):

Hi I tried the same with the below pasted code. It works fine for me

```
CCString* keyString = CCString::createWithFormat("仕事");
CCLabelTTF * pLabelTTF = CCLabelTTF::create(keyString->getCString(), "Arial", 40.0f);
pLabelTTF->setColor(ccc3(100, 100, 100));
pLabelTTF->setPosition(ccp(origin.x+visibleSize.width/2, origin.y+visibleSize.height/2));
pLabelTTF->setZOrder(15);
this->addChild(pLabelTTF);
```

Output : http://screencast.com/t/hJuRua75JwB

Comment: Oh, i have tried, it works fine with that one. My fault, i did not explain enough. cause i have an array like: static char* textlist[5] ={"仕事","仕事","仕事","仕事","仕事"} then i get value from that array and add 5 CClabelTTF but when i debug it's "???", please tell me what i was wrong? thank you

Comment: static char* textlist[5] ={"仕","仕事","仕事","仕事","仕事"};
    CCLabelTTF * pLabelTTF = CCLabelTTF::create(textlist[0],   "Arial", 40.0f);